# Can TortoiseGit email me when someone has pushed

Tags: smtp, push, tortoisegit

I've added my SMTP info under Network => Email settings.

Will TortoiseGit email me that someone pushed an update?

If not, how is the SMTP info used?

Answer (score 0):

> Will TortoiseGit email me that someone pushed an update?

No, TortoiseGit does not have this feature.

TortoiseGit is client-side tool. The feature you asked is server-side feature gerenally.

If you want your coworker to notify you via email when they push commits, you can fire a new TortoiseGit issue [here](https://tortoisegit.org/issues).

> If not, how is the SMTP info used?

It's used for sending patch via email.

Comment: I know it's client-side. Figured it might have an option to ping the repo every so often to check the status.

Comment: There is a similar [TortoiseGit issue #2296](https://tortoisegit.org/issues/2296) which implement a feature that is used to notify user someone pushed commits to server. But, it's not via email, suppose no need to do so.